# Draw 3D shapes in perspective with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, tikz-3d

Is it possible to draw a parallelepiped in perspective such as shown in the figure below (with colors, transparency, edges, etc)? Is it easily feasible using tikz or do I need other library?

Notes: the red and blue circles at top left and right are the vanishing points. I put the origin at one corner (point O) so that defining the height (Oz), width (Ox) and length (Oy) is sufficient to get the shape. Maybe the vanishing points could be defined by a pair of coordinates such as (radius, angle) with respect to a 2D system of axis. I am just especulating these ideas and I really have no idea on how to do this. That's why I can't provide any MWE (sorry).

[image]

### **EDIT:**

After the comment by @HenriMenke directing to the tikz manual, I tried the following simple code extracted directly from the very document. However, compiling in Overleaf prints nothing and results in errors.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{perspective}

\newcommand\simplecuboid[3]{%
    \fill[gray!80!white]
        (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=#3)
            -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=#2,z=#3)
            -- (tpp cs:x=#1,y=#2,z=#3)
            -- (tpp cs:x=#1,y=0,z=#3) -- cycle;
    \fill[gray]
        (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=0)
            -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=#3)
            -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=#2,z=#3)
            -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=#2,z=0) -- cycle;
    \fill[gray!50!white]
        (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=0)
            -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=#3)
            -- (tpp cs:x=#1,y=0,z=#3)
            -- (tpp cs:x=#1,y=0,z=0) -- cycle;
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[3d view, perspective={p={(2,0,0)},q={(0,2,0)},r={(0,0,2)}}]
    \simplecuboid{3}{1}{2}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is an example in the PGF manual. Unfortuantely nobody reads the manual. https://pgf-tikz.github.io/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf#section.63

Comment: Hello @HenriMenke. Thank you for pointing the direction. I just tried to load ```\usetikzlibrary{perspective}``` in Overleaf without success. :/

Comment: I copied your example code into an Overleaf document with both pdfTeX and LuaLaTeX, and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{perspective}

\newcommand\simplecuboid[3]{%
    \fill[red!50,opacity=0.5]
        (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=#3)
            -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=#2,z=#3)
            -- (tpp cs:x=#1,y=#2,z=#3)
            -- (tpp cs:x=#1,y=0,z=#3) -- cycle;
    \fill[red,opacity=0.5]
        (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=0)
            -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=#3)
            -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=#2,z=#3)
            -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=#2,z=0) -- cycle;
    \fill[red!80,opacity=0.5]
        (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=0)
            -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=#3)
            -- (tpp cs:x=#1,y=0,z=#3)
            -- (tpp cs:x=#1,y=0,z=0) -- cycle;
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    3d view={-55}{80},
    perspective={
    p = {(2,0,0)},
    q = {(0,2,0)}},
    scale=3,
    vanishing point/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=1pt},
    cuboid point/.style={fill,circle,inner sep=1pt}]
    
    \node[vanishing point,fill=cyan!50,label = right:p] (p) at (2,0,0){};
    \node[vanishing point,fill=red,label = left:q] (q) at (0,2,0){};

    \foreach \y in {0,1.5}{
        \draw[red!20!black] (tpp cs:x=0,y=\y,z=0) -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=\y,z=2);
        \draw[red!20!black] (tpp cs:x=1,y=\y,z=0) -- (tpp cs:x=1,y=\y,z=2);
        \foreach \z in {0,2}{
            \draw[dotted] (tpp cs:x=1,y=\y,z=\z) -- (p.center);
            \draw[red!30!black] (tpp cs:x=0,y=\y,z=\z) -- (tpp cs:x=1,y=\y,z=\z);}}
    \foreach \x in {0,1}{
        \foreach \z in {0,2}{
            \draw[dotted] (tpp cs:x=\x,y=1.5,z=\z) -- (q.center);
            \draw[red!20!black] (tpp cs:x=\x,y=0,z=\z) -- (tpp cs:x=\x,y=1.5,z=\z);}}

    
    \simplecuboid{1}{1.5}{2}

    \begin{scope}[every node/.style={cuboid point, anchor=center}]
        \node[label=above:{$x$}] at (tpp cs:x=0,y=1.5,z=2) {};
        \node[label=above:{$y$}] at (tpp cs:x=1,y=1.5,z=2) {};
        \node[label=above:{$z$}] at (tpp cs:x=1,y=0,z=2) {};
        \node[label=below:{$O$}] at (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=0) {};
    \end{scope}
    \node[label={[label distance=-3pt,rotate=60]below:{\small$Ox$}}] at (tpp cs:x=0.5,y=0,z=0) {};
    \node[label={[label distance=-3pt,rotate=-30]below:{\small$Oy$}}] at (tpp cs:x=0,y=0.75,z=0) {};
    \node[label={[rotate=90]above:{\small$Oz$}}] at (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]